# How to store homemade pasta

Tags: storage-method, pasta

When I prepare homemade egg pasta (tagliatelle, fettuccine, spaghetti, etc), which is the better way to store it?

I used to keep it in a cotton cloth, but sometimes it becomes moldy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always freeze my leftover fresh pasta.  I lay it flat on a cookie sheet, place it in the freezer for a couple of hours, and then when it is frozen I transfer it into a Tupperware container.  I always use a rigid container instead of freezer bag as the bag does not protect against breakage when the pasta is moved around in the freezer.

Comment: Agreed.  Excellent method.  And if you want to keep it fresh for a few days, I would recommend letting it dry thoroughly.